# Android JNI not packed in APK

Tags: android, java-native-interface, renderscript

I'm using the Android `Renderscript` native library but the `*.so` files aren't packed in my `APK` when I export it.

The application works perfectly when I run it throught `Eclipse` but this is clearly a pack issue with the `APK` file:

```
Caused by: android.support.v8.renderscript.r: Error loading RS jni library: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: unknown failure
```

What am I supposed to do to add the `*.so` files in the `APK` ?

Comment: If the app works, this is probably just a benign message from the backport, looking for something that isn't needed in your current environment.

Comment: The app works in `Eclipse` run mode, but not once it has been packed. And this is not a benign message as the app crashes.

Comment: What is "Eclipse run mode"? What is "packed"?

Comment: `Eclipse run mode` is the "Green play button" in eclipse and `packed mode` is the Android "Export signed application"

Comment: I forgot to mention that my `Proguard` is enabled

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Solution was to add this line to the ProGuard file

```
-keep class android.support.v8.renderscript.** { *; }
```